# How to weight paint one side of a face

Tags: weight-painting, geometry-nodes

[image]I am trying to make a very, very rough model of a cochlea. I have the spiral and I am trying to create the hairs. However, the spiral needs to be open. I don't know if this was a bad idea or not, but I deleted half of the mesh so you could see inside. The problem now is I cannot weight paint only one side of the mesh. I have already tried extruding the mesh slightly downward, but the results were not flattering. That was the only solution I could think of. Is there a way to paint only one side of a face, or some way to make two faces while one is not visible? My problem is I don't want the bristles to appear on the outside but rather only the inside. I'm super new to blender.

Comment: hello, could you please show a screenshot of your object?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I roughly know what's going on with your mesh. I have a solution that I think might help you.

You can add a mirror modifier onto your mesh to create another side of it. However, don't click apply until you are ready. It essentially just shows you what it would look like mirrored until you click apply, in which it creates the geometry for the other side.